# MvvmCross - Wpf CustomPresenter

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross

I'm trying to use a MvxWpfViewPresenter to navigate from one view to another, but i'm having some problems when trying to present it with IMvxWpfViewsContainer.

I have registered the IMvxWpfViewsContainer in my App.Xaml.Mvx.cs and added my ViewModel to it.

```
private void DoSetup()
{
    LoadMvxAssemblyResources();

    var presenter = new MvxWpfPresenter(MainWindow);

    var setup = new Setup(Dispatcher, presenter);
    setup.Initialize();

    Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxWpfViewsContainer, MvxWpfViewsContainer>();
    var viewContainer = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxWpfViewsContainer>();
    viewContainer.Add<MyViewModel, MyView>(); //Adding my view to the IMvxWpfViewsContainer

    var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
    start.Start();

    _setupComplete = true;
}
```

In my MvxWpfPresenter i'm getting the default request from the MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(rootHint.NewRootType) but the IMvxWpfViewsContainer is throwing an exception in the next line when trying to CreateView for my request. My presenter is:

```
public class MvxWpfPresenter : MvxWpfViewPresenter
{
    private readonly Window _mainWindow;

    public MvxWpfPresenter(Window mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public override void Present(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        (_mainWindow.Content as Grid).Children.Clear();
        (_mainWindow.Content as Grid).Children.Add(frameworkElement);
    }

    public override void ChangePresentation(Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        if (hint is MvxRootPresentationHint)
        {
            var rootHint = hint as MvxRootPresentationHint;
            var requestTranslator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxWpfViewsContainer>();
            var view = MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(rootHint.NewRootType);
            Present(requestTranslator.CreateView(view));
        }
        else
        {
            base.ChangePresentation(hint);
        }
    }
```

The exception being thrown is:

```
An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find view for MySolution.Core.ViewModels.MyViewModel
```

Am I registering it the wrong way or am I forgetting something?

The Stack is:

```
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewsContainer.GetViewType(Type viewModelType)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Views.MvxWpfViewsContainer.CreateView(MvxViewModelRequest request)
at MySolution.MvxWpfPresenter.ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint) in **MYPATH**\MvxWpfPresenter.cs:line 32
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Views.MvxWpfViewDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ChangePresentation>b__3()
at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatcher.ExceptionMaskedAction(Action action)
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to add any more detail about the exception - e.g. is there a stacktrace?

Comment: I added the stack to the question, sorry for forgetting

Comment: Just found the error, gonna post here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the problem in my code. I'm gonna post here the answer in case someone has the same problem.

When i was registering the IMvxWpfViewsContainer, i was just registering it. Instead i had to Register it as a singleton.

So the solution is to modify the code from:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxWpfViewsContainer, MvxWpfViewsContainer>();
```

To:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxWpfViewsContainer>(() => new MvxWpfViewsContainer());
```

Comment: Daniel, can you shed more light on your setup? I'm not sure how to use the ViewsContainer.

Comment: You should use it in the presenter as shown above. You register your view/viewmodels to it in the setup: "viewContainer.Add<MyViewModel, MyView>()", and in your view presenter you create the requesttranslator as shown above to create the View for the ViewModel. I don't know how to make it clearer, because I don't know what you did not understand. If you can, create a question with your doubt so that I can or someone else can answer it